# SQLite select all return after first not found

Tags: python, sqlite

I am repeatedly selecting from a database and would like to speed the calls up. The database table I am calling is sorted such that the values I am looking for are located one after another. So if I have found one then if the next is not equal to the value I am looking for I dont need to search anymore. Current code continues searching though entire database - how can I exit after first non find after first find?

```
def select_all_where(cursor, col_name, table_name, colval):
    sql = "SELECT * FROM "+table_name+ " WHERE "+col_name+" = "+"'"+colval+"'"  
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return rows
```

Example table:

```
Id    TableId   Attribute   Value
1     23        'name'      'fred'
2     23        'name'      'sue'
3     2         'type'      'person'
```

For example I am looking for all TableId = '23', once the id is >2 I don't need to search anymore.

Comment: Do you have any indexes?

Comment: @CL , no indexes. I thought one way would be to select a single row (first), then use the id of that row to keep selecting the next row and checking if the tableid is the required value, if not then return.

Comment: Why don't you consider an index?

Comment: @CK, I will look into it, thanks.